# Use Python Script to skip bad rows in fixed width file when using COPY command for postgresql (Amazon Redshift)

Tags: python, sql, amazon-redshift, psycopg2

I am using psycopg2 to connect to a redshift database. I would like to run COPY queries to load fixed width files into tables, but some of these files have rows with errors in them. COPY currently breaks on the first error, and I would like to use a python script to skip these bad rows, log the error, and continue loading the data.
Is this advisable (as in good practice/convention)? If it is, how do I go about it?

Comment: Any script you use would have to clean the rows before they are built into a data set that could be passed to `COPY`. You cannot do this while `COPY` is running as the first error would cancel the operation. Another way to do this is to create a staging table that has no constraints and has all `varchar` fields and `COPY` into that, assuming the errors are caused by constraint or data type issues. Then clean the data there before sending it to the final table.

Comment: This seems to be the way to go with this. I'll explore it. Thank you very much. @AdrianKlaver